# Ionic 3/4 - Daily Local Notifications not working

Tags: ionic-framework, notifications, ionic3, uilocalnotification, ionic4

Local notifications don't work properly (tried it with ionic 3 & 4).
The user can set a time in the app and turn the notifications on or off.
When using the following code, I always get a notification at 01:00 am although I've set it to 17:30 or something else.
I tried many variations, this is the last one:

```
const time = setsub.task_reminder_time.split(':');
    const now = new Date();
    console.log('now is', now);
    const pushDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), +time[0], +time[1], 0);
    const options = {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Time to plan your day!',
      text: `Hey you! It's time to get productive by planning your day!\nTap here to open DoDay! `,
      trigger: { firstAt: pushDate, every: ELocalNotificationTriggerUnit.DAY }
    };
    if (setsub.task_reminder) {
      this.notification.requestPermission();
      this.notification.schedule(options);
    } else {
      this.notification.clearAll();
    }
```

`time` is just a string containing the notification time in HH:mm
I'm using an iOS device for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution to this one by myself. It's an error in the typings file of LocalNotifications package.

The correct usage for the options look like this:

```
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Notification Title',
      text: 'Your notification text',
      foreground: true,
      trigger: {
        every: {
          hour: 8,
          minute: 15
        }
      }
    }
```

Just go into your `node_modules/@ionic-native/local-notifications` find the index.d.ts and find the line which says `every?: ELocalNotificationTriggerUnit` and change it to `every?: any;` now it should work perfectly.